# protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.4

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, carla

"protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.4"

Dear community,
I'm using CARLA simulator and for that I need to use python 3.6 and protobuf.
When I want to install 'protobuf' I get this error "protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.4"
Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Update your Python to >= 3.7 since CARLA should also be compatible with that version. 
[see under C.](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/)

Comment: Python 3.6 is [out of support](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Protobuf isn't the only package that no longer supports it. Upgrade to a supported version, preferably 3.10.

Answer (score 6):

You can install the package that works in python version 3.6. link below [link](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/3.19.6/)

how to install:
`pip install protobuf==3.19.6`

Comment: That's not a real solution - Python 3.6 is out of support. Many packages have dropped support for this already. Protobuf may work but then something else will break

Comment: I don't think you have any choice but to install the version that works in version 3.6. Others are incompatible.